# Knockout.Js Hiding Parent if Child Empty/Removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm in a bit of a (data-)bind (...bad joke).

So, I have the following (closing omitted)

```
            <div id="allMessages" data-bind="foreach: filteredMessagesTime">
            <div class="messageHolder">
                <div class="messageBody">
                <div class="messageFooter">
                    <div class="commentSection">
                        <ul class="ulIterator" data-bind="foreach: $root.filteredCommentsTime(MessageComments)">
                            <li class="commentHolder">
```

I want to show the `messageHolder` only if I actually have a comment, i.e. `commentHolder` exists.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `if` or `visible` binding depending on if you want to remove it from the DOM or just hide it.

```
<div id="allMessages" data-bind="foreach: filteredMessagesTime">
    <!-- ko if: $root.filteredCommentsTime(MessageComments).length > 0 -->
        <div class="messageHolder">
            <div class="messageBody">
                <div class="messageFooter">
                    <div class="commentSection">
                        <ul class="ulIterator" data-bind="foreach: $root.filteredCommentsTime(MessageComments)">
                            <li class="commentHolder">
        ....................
    <!-- /ko -->
```